# clustering for trajectories

Tags: python, gis, data-mining, cluster-analysis, modeling

I have large amount of temporal lat/lon.

I'm trying to find k-clusters of trajectories from this data. What is the best approach for this?

Thanks.

Edit:

How should I generate the features for my data (lat/lon + time) in order to use kmeans / hierarchical clustering?

Edit:

Hopefully this will make it clearer

Here's an example of how my data look:

```
Trajectory 1:

lat1,lon1 at time1
lat2,lon2 at time2
...
lat55,lon55 at time55
```

```
Trajectory 2:

lat343,lon343 at time343
lat344,lon344 at time344
...
lat376,lon376 at time376
```

And on and on (couple more trajectories).

So say I have 200 of these trajectories, I want to cluster them into 2 groups. How should I approach this?

Should I use kmeans/HAC for this or should I look at another method?

Edit:

The goal of this is to classify the trajectories into k clusters which represent k different directions of the trajectories.

Simply, I am just trying to cluster the trajectories into groups of different directions. I am not worried about their **distances** similarities.

So say the end I want to find something like this:

```
Direction 1:
Trajectory 4
Trajectory 5
Trajectory 7
```

```
Direction 2:
Trajectory 44
Trajectory 2
Trajectory 27
```

...

```
Direction 10:
Trajectory 17
Trajectory 8
```

Note: The shapes of the trajectories are mostly lines (not straight-lines), some are looped.
Note: The lat/lon are super local to one region, so I can use a flat-earth approximation.

The directions are intended to be very coarse. How do I compute similarity between trajectories to cluster them to achieve this?

Edit:

Here is an illustration (to the best of my abilities):

[image: Trajectories and End result]

I want to separate the trajectories into the directions as such.

Comment: I'm not getting your point here exactly.. is what you are asking for is feature extraction? if so, then it has nothing to do with clustering.

Comment: No, I'm not asking about feature extraction. I'm asking about how to cluster trajectories given lat/lon + time for each lat/lon. Say that I know the number of clusters to be 2, how would I cluster the trajectories into 2 clusters? I can't do something naive like using end lat/lon and subtracting the beginning lat/lon.

Comment: OK, I'm not 100% sure here because the case is not that clear to me (anyway it's hard to describe a case of DM within a couple of lines). but have you tried k-means for those three dimensions you mentioned (lat/lon + time). euclidean distance would help you to process the k-means with `centroids` and everything else.. Am I closer to your point now?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Hopefully my edit should make it clearer

Comment: @ktklam9: What are you trying to use these data to determine? A simple density raster (computed using IDW or Kriging) would be a simple approximation, or consider constructing a vector field, clustered into grid cells. (Aside: are those airborne particle trajectories? I gave [a talk last year at the AMS conference](https://ams.confex.com/ams/92Annual/webprogram/Paper199413.html) about analyzing just such a dataset.)

Comment: @ktklam9 - it depends on the goal here, If you want to have a distance similarity then you need an algorithm like  `Haversine formula`.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Haversine formula will not help me because these lat/lon are local to one region, so I am using a flat-earth approximation.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Can you expand more on constructing a vector field?

Comment: @ktklam9 - I think it's better to describe your goal here. then you can have better suggestions.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Can you look at my goal in the edit? How can I improve on this clarification?

Comment: Ok, I don't see that you need to use clustering here. as all you have is one region. clustering intends to cluster all the similar observations into a group. which is called `inner-cluster` and the similarity should be minimized (not similar) between the clusters.
what I think is you need to get classification algorithm to work around here. this is just a suggestion after all :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Supervised classification (if I understand you correctly) will not work here as I don't know the classes of the clusters beforehand to train a NN or a SVM.

Comment: @ktklam9: Do all your trajectories have the same origin point (or at least the same spatial origin point?) In that case, a simple heat map should might be all you need -- for meteorological data, a [wind rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_rose) is a common way to represent this kind of data. I think this question would be a lot easier to answer if you could draw a picture of your trajectories and a picture of what you want your result to look like.

Comment: @DanielPryden: No, they don't have the same origin point. I edited the question with an illustration if it helps.

Comment: Next question: What if the yellow trajectory did not deviate at the end but followed the blue and green trajectories while having a much smaller length (same as in the example, so it stops short). Would you then consider it in the same group? If the answer is yes it gets quite tricky, because the yellow deviation from the blue and green looks subtle to me. In that case, a slight nudge to the yellow trajectory (to the right) makes it change groups, and this is hard to get right. If the answer is no, can you assume anything about the lenght of trajectories in one group: should they be similar?

Comment: It seems that you know your classes from the last edit.

Comment: @micans: What do you mean by "followed the blue and green trajectories"? The illustration shows how I want to cluster the trajectories.

Answer (score 4):

K-means is designed around *minimizing variance*.

When you apply it to longitudinal data, you get some error unless you are always close to the equator and stay away from the 180 meridian. Because the earth is approximately a *sphere surface*, not an infinite euclidean vector space.

Try a distance or density based clustering algorithm instead that can **use great-circle distance**, for example. Hierarchical clustering may be a better choice than k-means, too.

Great-circle distance is just between two points. So the next thing for *you* to do is to figure out how to combine these distances and the temporal component into an appopriate **similarity measure** for your trajectories. This is quite usage dependant, and there is no universal solution that we could share with you. **The better your similarity function, the better your clustering results!**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. I am not clustering purely lat/lon data. I'm trying to cluster the trajectories into k-clusters given by the lat/lon + a time component.

Comment: Yes, and are the clusters meaningful, given that k-means does not understand "latitude", "longitude", "time" and their relationship? See, it assumes an euclidean vector space. But the earth surface is approximately a sphere surface.

Comment: I see why you are concerned about using kmeans for lat/lon. I still dont think it matters because the lat/lon are super local to one region, so I can assume a flat-earth approximation.

Comment: Well, doesn't hold for me, I have data sets that contain Alaska.
Furthermore, in Europe the distortion is already like 1/3 - flat earth is a really bad approximation. Equirectangular is easy to use, but about the worst map projection you can choose. It preserves neither angles nor distances nor area.

Comment: So say even if I don't use a flat-earth approximation, why can't I use k-means? I can transform the lat/lon into cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) and use that. But again, I doubt this or your suggestion will help in clustering the trajectories.

Comment: Because it handles outliers very well. So even if you e.g. used `(lon*1.3, lat)` to correct for the bias where `1.3` is chosen appropriately for your latitude, k-means is an aggressive partitioning to minimize variance that doesn't handle outliers too well.
Plus, this still is for *single observations* not for actual trajectories.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25228/discussion-between-ktklam9-and-anony-mousse)

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe the problem it sounds as if you can represent all trajectories as an angle relative to the equator. It then comes down to segmenting; this is not really clustering; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization. In your case the values would loop around, so it would be segmenting values on a circle (using degrees/angles) rather than on a straight line. Of course, if this describes your problem, it also provides a good way of visualising it.

Comment: No, I cannot represent the trajectories as an angle because they are not straight-lines. It is not clear how I would use the Jenks natural breaks optimization on my data. Can you explain further?

Comment: Well, you write "The directions are intended to be very coarse. So Direction 1 could be like North to South, while Direction 2 could be from South to North etc...". This is certainly representable as a straight line / angle. I understand this describes your desired outcome, but it seems logical to then abstract your input to the same level. If you do *not* want to compress the input to such a crude representation, then the question arises: How do you compute similarity between trajectories? That seems to be the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW) produces a similarity metric that is typically used with time-series data (which is what you have). You can then use these DTW similarities as input to any of a number of similarity-based clustering algorithms.

For your dataset, I would extract sequences of orientations only because including the distance component could lead to problems if paths are traversed at different speeds or if samples are taken at heterogeneous time intervals.